# Troubleshooting grep not returning whole lines during search?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

I have two tab delimited txt files- `FileA` has 30,000 lines and 10 columns. `FileB` has 600 lines and 1 column. My goal is to search the 30,000 lines of `FileA` using the search terms in `FileB` and output the whole line from `FileA` that contains the search term.
I have run

```
grep -Fwf FileB FileA
```

(and other variations with/without the flags)
but every time I get zero output. 
If I edit `FileA` to only have its first column, I get results but obviously I'm missing the 9 columns of data I would like.

Does anyone have any advice? I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Is there some way to incorporate `awk` into this to make it work? If it is of any use, I am using Git Bash as my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue arose from these being Excel files saved as a .txt files. I used awk to print all columns from from FileA into a new file (FileA1.txt) and to be on the safe side I did the same with FileB (FileB1.txt). At that point, when I ran

```
grep -Fwf FileB1.txt FileA1.txt
```

my results were exactly what I was looking for.